# In Rally: Can I map custom task states to existing Task states in a Rally Task Board (similar to Kanban for user stories)?

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

What would it take to create a TASK card board with mappable states like Rally's existing Kanban board supports.

I would like to add one or two custom task states: like "ready to merge" and "unit test complete".  The existing task board doesn't support this feature.

I played with the card board code using the Rally 2.0 SDK (preview) and was able to quickly display tasks in custom state columns, but the mapping is where I got lost, as I am unsure how to map these custom states to the default Defined/In-Process/Completed states.  I was curious if you had any pointers as to what triggers or components to use for state mapping.

I know there can be some opposition to additional task states, but in some engineering firms, where coding is closely tied to tasks, additional states can make sense at the task level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me give you some caveats.
Your mappings will only work for this specific board and any other view. So the changes can get out of sync fairly easily.

Here is some code that should do what you are expecting. You can get gist for it here
https://gist.github.com/2926610

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Custom App</title>

<!--Include SDK-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p/sdk.js"></script>

<!--App code-->
<script type="text/javascript">

    Rally.onReady(function() {

        Ext.define('CustomApp', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',
            mappedToField:"State",
            mappedFromField:"Mapme",

            fieldNameMap:{
                a:"Defined",
                b:"Defined",
                c:"In-Progress",
                d:"In-Progress",
                e:"Completed"
            },

            launch: function() {
                this.add({
                    xtype:'rallycardboard',
                    types:['task'],
                    attribute: this.mappedFromField,
                    listeners:{
                        beforecarddroppedsave:function(cardboard, card) {
                            //map the new state from on this card to the new state
                            var newState = this.fieldNameMap[card.record.get(this.mappedFromField)];
                            card.record.set(this.mappedToField, newState);
                        },
                        scope:this
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name: 'My Custom App'
        });

    });

</script>


</head>
<body class="myApp">
</body>
</html>
```